# Remove lines ending with a specific format in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, text-editing

I've got a simple array in Notepad++:

```
bla.vmt"
bla.vtf"
bla_exponent.vtf"
```

I want to get rid of the lines ending with `.vmt` and `_exponent.vtf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove lines ending with `.vmt`, use Search and Replace and select the Regular Expression option. Give the regular expression as

```
[^%]*.vmt
```

This will replace all lines that end with `.vmt`.

---

Similarly, to replace lines ending with `_exponent.vtf`, use:

```
[^%]*_exponent.vtf
```

as the regular expression.

---

The regular expression `[^%]*` means
match all characters other than `%`.

Comment: Since Notepad++ 6.0 PCRE regex is used, so `[^%]` will also match newline characters. This solution will match far too much and even anchors to the end of the row are missing.

Answer (score 5):

Similar to what Raam answered, but with the regular expressions

```
^.*\.vmt"$

^.*_exponent\.vtf"$
```

The dot before the extension should also be escaped with backslash.

^ marks the beginning of a line.

$ marks the ending of a line.

Answer (score 4):

1. Use Find to mark all lines

   1. Ctrl + F to open the Find screen
   2. Go to the "Mark" Tab
   3. Check "Bookmark line" option
   4. Check the Regular expression option
   5. Use `vmt$` as regex to find all lines ending with "vmt". `$` is the regex anchor that matches the end of a row.
   6. Press "Mark All"
2. Go to the "**Search**" menu, "**Bookmarks ==> Remove Bookmarked lines**"

Similar for your other case, you can use `exponent\.vtf` as regex. To match a literal "." with regex, you have to escape it `\.`, because it is a  special character in regex.

Comment: This is my chosen answer because it actually gets rid of the lines instead of just clearing them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if regex has changed since, but as for me, the working regular expression was:

```
(.*).vmt$
```

(.*) select the whole line before the .vmt extension